# Inserting data to other xls workbook via ADO & SQL – Data type error

Tags: sql, excel, connection, vba

I am building a quite complex UserForm that uses ADO connection to connect to another Excel workbook that serves as a database and retrieve & insert data via SQL queries. Please note I am not allowed to use Access in this case.

I have already figured out how to use SELECT, but there is one particular error with INSERT I can't resolve. That bothers me a lot, I've put a lot of work to it.

First the connection (I use JET for retrieving data and ACE for saving data as I was not able to get JET to work for that):

```
Public Sub InsertDataToSheet(SQLCmd As String)
Dim cnx As Object
Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cnx.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.xls'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
cnx.Execute SQLCmd
cnx.Close
End Sub
```

Then there is a subroutine linked to a Submit button that actually generates the Query as I need to save only filled out Textboxes and Combos to avoid Nulls:

```
Private Sub SaveRecord()

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "INSERT INTO [Report$A2:AM50000] ("

Dim i As Control
For Each i In Me.controls
    If TypeName(i) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(i) = "ComboBox" Then
        If i <> e Then SQL = SQL & i.Name & ","
    End If
Next i
SQL = Mid(SQL, 1, Len(SQL) - 1) & ") VALUES(" ' Remove last space & comma

Dim j As Control
For Each j In Me.controls
    If TypeName(j) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(j) = "ComboBox" Then
        If j <> e Then
            If j = "Unknown" Then MsgBox "Fire"
            Select Case IsNumeric(j)
                Case False
                        SQL = SQL & "'" & j & "'" ' Add single quotes around strings
                Case True
                        SQL = SQL & j
            End Select
            SQL = SQL & ","
        End If
    End If
Next j
SQL = Mid(SQL, 1, Len(SQL) - 1) & ")"   ' Remove last comma
' Connect
InsertDataToSheet (SQL)
End Sub
```

There are two particular textboxes in the form that work exactly the same. Normally, users enter numbers to them and everything saves fine (don't mind the '+' buttons):

[image]

Sometimes, however, users do not know the values but can't leave those empty. That's when they are supposed to tick the checkboxes to set the value(s) to 'Unknown':

[image]
Now there comes the funny part – for the Batch field, it saves fine. But when I set the Shipment ID to 'Unknown' (or any other string), it throws an error:

[image]

Note the fields are not Disabled, just Locked with some appearance changes. I was also unable to find any specific details about the error, but it seems there is some problem with the query:

[image]

(It says something like 'Incompatible data types in the expression'). The generated query is this:

[image]

Any ideas what goes wrong? I'd very much like to keep the functionality as it is know and solve the error rather than redesign it as it already took some effort and the fields can't stay empty.

Comment: Is this the error you are getting? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?43288-Run-time-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used sql in xls workbooks, but I had this problem with SQL server already. There's nothing "wrong" with your query, the problem is that data type that's accepted on the field of the table you want to insert. Try to turn that field to use text values instead of numbers and it should work.